# Networked processes constantly crashing within Hyper-V virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, crash

I have a persistent problem with the networked processes on my virtual machine. This is a Hyper-V virtual machine in an enchanced session hosted on my own physical machine and using up most of its resources (12092 MB of static memory and three virtual processors) which I perform most of my day-to-day computer use on. I do this so that I can make use of the Hyper-V checkpointing features and avoid losing my entire session.

The networked processes on my virtual machine are constantly terminating without warning. The more networked processes are running, the more likely one is to terminate, and the more active a process is, the more likely it is to terminate. Sometimes two processes will terminate at the same time. Even the process which connects with the host machine is subject to this, meaning the virtual machine will sometimes disconnect without warning. None of this happens with non-networked processes, and nothing like it happens on the host machine (which I do still use for some purposes). I do run a VPN in my virtual machine but have already ruled it out as the cause (disabling it doesn't fix).

Both machines are running Windows 10. Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I might try to resolve this problem?

EDIT: My physical CPU is an Intel Core i7-8665u @ 1.90 GHz. My physical motherboard is a Lenovo 20N2A040NZ (it's a ThinkPad T490). My network card is a Intel Wireless-AC 9560 160Mhz.

Comment: Please specify details on your (physical) hardware, especially brand/model of CPU, motherboard and NIC. You can edit your own question to add that information. Having said that: 1st thing to try is to disable power-management on the NIC driver. That is always the first thing to check with network issues in Windows.

Comment: Hi, added the specs for the physical hardware although I will note again that this only occurs on the virtual machine. But I have disabled power management on my physical network card and will let you know if that helps.

Comment: A T490... I happen to have one of those lying around myself and had similar issues with Hyper-V stability due to power-management. Had to disable it on the NIC and run host AND guest Windows installation in "High Performance" mode all the time. It's not just the T490. I've seen similar issues with many 7thh Gen (and later) Core-i based laptops. It seems to me that Microsoft, in an effort to be "green", is often too extreme on the power-management.

Comment: Another thing: Stability might be better with 2 or 4 vCPU's. It is very unusual to run with an odd # of cores (other than 1) and no OS I know of is optimized to handle that well....